# Django An invalid form control with name='' is not focusable

Tags: html, django, django-forms, django-crispy-forms

I created a Django form that have dropdown in one of the field. When I tried to submit the form without selecting the dropdown item, the form is not submitted because I set in my code that it won't submit unless the form valid using `is_valid()`.
However, it was not showing the validation error message. In the browser console, the is an error message `An invalid form control with name='start_position' is not focusable.`

I have read some questions about this and they said that it happened because there is a hidden field. After I inspect element, it is true that div class='start_position' is hidden.
However, I don't know how to fix it in Django.

This is the code that create dropdown field.

```
class LocationForm(forms.Form):
    start_position = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        required=True,
        label="Start Position",
        queryset=Location.objects.all()
    )
```

This is the rendered HTML

```
<div class="formColumn form-group col-md-6 mb-0">
  <div id="div_id_start_position" class="form-group">
    <label for="id_start_position" class="col-form-label  requiredField">
      Start Position<span class="asteriskField">*</span>
    </label> <div class="">
    <select name="start_position" class="select form-control" required="" id="id_start_position" style="display: none;">
      <option value="" selected="">---------</option>
      <option value="78">Loc 78</option>
      <option value="79">Loc 79</option>
      <option value="80">Loc 80</option>
    </select><div class="nice-select select form-control" tabindex="0"> 
    <span class="current">Loc 78</span>
    <ul class="list">
      <li data-value="" class="option">---------</li>
      <li data-value="78" class="option selected">Loc 78</li>
      <li data-value="79" class="option">Loc 79</li>
      <li data-value="80" class="option">Loc 80</li>
    </ul></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want the validation message show like in the other field (I tried `DateField` and the validation works normally).

Comment: You've got required=True show it is using JavaScript validation to ensure something is entered.

Comment: Can you post the rendered html?

Comment: @svrw I have added the rendered html in the question.

Comment: How do you render this in the template?

Comment: @svrw I use django crispy form, so in template there is `{% crispy form %}`

Comment: Why is it set to display:none though? What is doing that?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I don't know. It is automatically generated by django form.